# What Framework is Facebook using for iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, frameworks

Does anyone have any idea on what framework Facebook App, and Flixster App are using to create the custom detail view look that slides on the side. I have looked all over and havent found anything, but thought that it may be worth asking.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook traditionally implements their own UI and releases much of it as open source code in the [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) library.  However, it does not look like Three20 has gotten an update since the new Facebook was released.

Here is another open source implementation that uses this functionality: https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo

Answer (score 0):

Given the vast amount of engineering talent Facebook has, I would be surprised if they were using some 3rd party framework for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook released their UI tools for iOS on Github. It's called three20. You can check out the source here: https://github.com/facebook/three20.